# Trouble Finding Xamarin Templates in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, android, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

**Question:**

I'm currently trying to set up Xamarin for Android development in Visual Studio 2022, but I'm having difficulty finding the Xamarin templates. I've installed the necessary components like .NET MAUI and Android development with .NET (Xamarin), but when I go to create a new project, I only see options like "Class Library (Android)" and "Blank App (Android)." I'm unable to find Xamarin.Forms templates or other Xamarin-related templates.

**Steps I've Taken:**

- Installed Visual Studio 2022 with the "Individual components" for .NET MAUI and Xamarin.

  2.Checked the "Available" tab to ensure the required components are selected

  3.Restarted Visual Studio after making changes.

**Question Details:**

- How can I ensure that Xamarin.Forms templates are available in Visual Studio 2022?
- Are there specific workloads or components I might be missing?
- Any suggestions on troubleshooting this issue?

I appreciate any guidance or insights. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Visual Studio Installer, under "Workloads -> Installation Details -> .NET Multi-Platform App UI development", check both the "Android SDK setup" and the "Xamarin" option.

[image]

The project template is called "Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)".

[image]